# How to handle a string containing .net new line character in javascript

Tags: javascript

Page cannot be loading correctly while assigning a string which contains newline character(\r\n) in to a hidden variable using javascript. 
(I am working in ASP.net MVC framework.)

```
$('#hdnTaskName').val('@Model.TaskScheduleInfo.TaskName')
```

How to resolve this problem??

Answer (score -1):

use `@Html.Raw()`

```
$('#hdnTaskName').val('@Html.Raw(Model.TaskScheduleInfo.TaskName)');
```